# How can a Mechromancer be optimized for Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode

Tags: borderlands-2

[Salpe86's Assassin's Guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/121482/6274) has been a great help in gearing my character up to better handle Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode. Since following his recommendations, I've gone from constantly fighting for my life and burning through handfuls of ammo clips when facing what should be the most trivial of enemies to killing even Badass-level monsters without having to reload more than once.

However, my wife hasn't been so lucky. She plays a Mechromancer and still has trouble even down to True Vault Hunter Mode. She only made it into UVHM with the help of my escorting her through the endgame missions of TVHM.

I presume the weapon selections recommended for Assassin will probably port over to Mechromancer fairly well, but are there any changes I should make to that - does the Mechromancer tend to handle some particular weapon types better or worse than Assassin? How about Shields, Artificats, and Class Mods? What skills are essential for a Mechromancer in UVHM?

Comment: Since my answer kept getting down-votes I deleted it. For anyone still looking for the vids: for lv 50: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c65uGxCF1yM and for lv 61:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMwDcP09VFY.  Good luck Iszi, sorry I was not able to help ya.

Answer (score 1):

wow, old question, so my answer is probably late.

I play a mechromancer.  I've not gotten to UHVM yet, but I've solo'd most of TVHM so far with very little problem (I do die occasionally, but I never got 'stuck')

I invest in anarchy (I keep the stack limit at 150) with maxed type I iconocast and rational anarchist.  I always pack a one-shot jakobs; even if its weak; purely to build anarchy; though you have to be far from the enemy and stay safe while you charge it up.  It takes very little time to get to 100 stacks and Deathtrap does a fine job at keeping them from getting to me while I charge up.  At about 100 stacks or so, I switch to my main guns and start chewing through enemies very quickly.  Anarchy, at least for me, has been key for Mechromancer.  Shotguns are your friend; 5/5 close enough, standing close to the enemy, and 150 stacks of anarchy = awesome offensive power.  Throw in 5/5 bloadsoaked shields and you can stay alive as long as you keep killing stuff; an easy thing to do with the anarchy/weapons mentioned above.

Rest of my points generally go into Best Friends Forever tree to beef up Deathtrap. He is seriously a beast even on TVHM late game; so long as you spec him for it.

I do admit; I am nervous to see how this build fares in UVHM..

Comment: +1, I haven't got far in UVHM with my mechromancer, but she's been stupidly overpowered since I started getting over 100 anarchy stacks on a regular basis and added in bouncing bullets. I regularly revive everybody else in the party multiple times in a fight without going down at all myself. Anarchy with a single shot shotgun is great advice. You don't need to hit anything ever. Just shoot the walls and ground near enemies.

Answer (score -1):

I have some idea for you 
1. Mechromancer must be use weapon with fastest reloading type :
Tediore
Jacobs
Hyperion

because almost all primary skill gaige activated during reloading process (example : Anarchy or Discord skill)
torgue weapon also good for necromancer but i recommend to invest in "Smaller, Lighter, Faster" skill in ordered chaos skill tree since torgue reload time is slow

2. normally you must learn 1 skill anarchy in order of chaos skill tree and after that is depending of your wife play style :
   best friend forever : use this skill tree if your wife really really like use deathtrap as back up
   little big trouble : primary for elementary weapon (especially shock type), is not powerful like siren skill tree but is good to burn your enemy (check Shock and "AAAGGGGHHH!" skill) 
   Ordered chaos : this skill tree can make your weapon 300x more powerful but this require high skill combat since to get 300 anarchy is not easy for some people

best friend forever & little big trouble is the most choice by many gamer